# Вводные слова, или какое определение у вводного слова

Tags: вводные-слова, частицы

Вопрос, как ясно из темы, таков: какое явное определение у вводного слова? Выделить через род и видовое отличие.

Вопрос возник ввиду трудности демаркации между частицами, например *вроде бы*, и вводными словами, например *наверное*.

Comment: При теме *Явное определение* метка «пунктуация»?

Comment: Да, как-то не в тему тег. Ваши предложения?

Comment: Из Справки: Если мотивация задающего — «желание обсудить что-либо», то следует воздержаться от публикации такого вопроса». (Вопрос неконкретен: начавшаяся дискуссия подтверждает).

Comment: Моя мотивация — получит нормальный ответ на вопрос, обсуждения проблемы (вопроса) — побочный продукт. В чём некорректность вопроса?

Comment: Если бы так было всё просто, то не нужно было бы искать, является слово/сочетание вводным или нет. Но есть у них особенность — это вставочный характер.

Comment: @oleedd, знаю об этом, потому и спрашиваю. Что такое вставочный характер? Некая интонация?

Comment: Да, интонация (хоть какая-то пауза до и после либо только с одной стороны), но не только. По интонации обычно можно определить, но не всегда это сработает, например, слово "наверно" настолько часто используется, что обычно вокруг него нет пауз. Он ещё проявляется в возможности изъятия без потери смысла. Но главное — это как своего рода комментарий к тексту.

Answer (score 1):

Вводные слова иначе называют  **модальными словами** (по их основной синтаксической функции).

1. Вообще говоря, **модальность** – это понятийная категория. Понятие модальности используется в различных областях науки, в частности в лингвистике. Существуют **частицы с модальным значением** (оценка достоверности, возможности, желательности и т.д.), а также модальными называют вводные слова. Они сходны с частицами по смыслу, но различаются грамматически.
2. **Частицы относятся к служебным частям речи**. Они придают различные дополнительные смысловые значения как словам, так и предложению в целом. Модальные частицы выражают отношение к действительности.
3. **Вводные слова**  называют модальными словами, так как модальность – их основное значение.  В современной вузовской практике модальные слова рассматривают **как особую часть речи** (для сравнения в Грамматике-80 их вообще не относили к частям речи).

Дело в том, что фактически вводные слова – это различные **знаменательные части** речи, употребленные в особой функции вводных слов. Они не являются членами предложения и не имеют грамматических связей с другими словами.  Для них определяется только синтаксическая функция.

*Он приедет **вроде бы** завтра.  – Он приедет завтра, **наверное.*** Слова **вроде бы** и **наверное**  имеют сходную семантику, но разную грамматику. Частица «вроде бы» относится к наречию, а вводное слово «наверное» характеризует отношение говорящего к содержанию высказывания, в состав предложения не входит и грамматических связей не имеет.

4. Таким образом, вводное (модальное)  слово является **частью речи с особыми характеристиками**, а частицы (с тем же модальным значением)  относятся к разряду служебных частей речи.

Comment: «Таким образом, вводное (модальное) слово является частью речи с особыми характеристиками…». — Вы не поверите, но и существительное, и прилагательное, и числительное, и прочие части речи являются частями речи с особыми характеристиками. Получается, они все — вводные слова?!

Если честно, я мало что понял из сказанного Вами, но скажу вот что: все вводные слова и некоторые частицы выражают модальность, а потому модальность не может быть видовым отличием вводного слова, иначе следует признать, что некоторые частицы являются вводными словами.

Comment: Каждая часть речи имеет определенные категориальные признаки, по которым слово относят к этой части речи. Это обобщенное семантическое значение, набор грамматических признаков и характерная синтаксическая роль в предложении.  А у вот у  вводных слов есть  только  особая синтаксическая функция, причем эту функцию выполняют другие части речи, и тогда они становятся вводными.  Неужели вы такие признаки  особыми не посчитаете? Модальными могут быть и частицы, но у них, кроме модальности, тоже есть эти категориальные признаки, по которым их относят к частицам.

Comment: Слово переходит в разряд вводных, если лишается этих признаков, а взамен получает вводную функцию.Может быть, теперь яснее стало, почему вводные слова - это особая часть речь, которую, кстати, не все лингвисты таковой признают. Но по вашим вопросам можно подумать, что у вас нет особого желания в этой теме разобраться. Ведь я с самого начала сказала, что модальность – обобщенное понятие, но вы этого не услышали.

Comment: Слишком много воды, воды и снова воды. Мне всего-то нужно явное определение через род и видовое отличие, ваше же определения слишком широкое по отношению к понятию (Dfd<Dfn). Всё.

Comment: Разумеется, всё. Я уже раз три назвала и род, и вид для вводных слов и частиц. Не четвертый же раз повторять!

Comment: @Sharon вы заметили потрясающую логику нашего необучаемого собеседника? Он честно заявил, что "мало что понял" из ваших объяснений, но это не помешало ему начать их критиковать. Потешная формула "не читал, но осуждаю" успешно сиим вопрошающим перерождена в "не понял, но критикую" :)

Comment: @Sharon, а мне, по-видимому, придётся Вас опять уведомить, что Ваши явные определения (их две штуки) ошибочны, предикаты «грамматическое различие», «модальность» и «особая синтаксическая функция» не являются видовым отличием, а предикат «вводная функция» был бы тавтологичным. Вот пример правильного явного определения: существительное — самостоятельная часть речи (род), которая указывает на предметы, лица и явление и отвечает на грамматические вопросы «кто?» и «что?» (видовое отличие). Но это как об стену горох. Идите учить логику.

Comment: @Argumentum  Уважаемый участник, а вы ничего не  перепутали? Это вы задаете нам вопрос и ПРОСИТЕ помочь разобраться в теме, а не наоборот. Хорошо, что вы хотя бы наконец поняли, по каким признакам слово относят к определенной части речи. Работайте и дальше в этом направлении. И не надо мне посылать «уведомления», поищите себе других друзей по переписке.

Comment: @Argumentum Сейчас (почему-то особенно два последних года) непризнанные гении везде толпами бродят, а уж по части логики  и «демаркации рода и вида» они вообще выдающиеся специалисты. Мы же занимаемся в основном практической грамотностью, то есть тем, что действительно нужно людям. Это всё, ОК? До свидания уже.

Answer (score 0):

Формальный признак вводности: *вводные слова и сочетания не связаны с членами предложения, не являются членами предложения.* То есть к такому слову/словосочетанию нельзя задать синтаксический вопрос.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134355/discussion-on-answer-by-nektoid-------).