# Мозготрах с вводными словами. Почему "По сути" - вводное, а "По факту" - нет?

Tags: вводные-слова

```
По сути, это война. 
По факту это война.
```

Почему 1-е предложение это вводная конструкция, а 2-е - нет?

Answer (score 1):

*"По факту" = "фактически"*, то есть наречие, не требует знаков препинания.

Что касается *"по сути"*, то оно может быть и не вводным.
**По сути, это война** — вводное слово, *"в сущности говоря"*.
**По сути это война** — член предложения; пример: *"По сути это война, а по форме — нет"*.

Comment: По такой логике имеем: "По факту" = "говоря по факту" - вводное, но может быть и не вводным. Ну а различия между "в сущности говоря это война" и "по своей сущности это война" существуют лишь по форме, но по смыслу их нет. А значит я всегда могу сказать, что вводное это невводное и наоборот без изменения смысла.

Comment: @user190920 различие по смыслу есть. Попробуйте заменить "в сущности" на "по сути" как член предложения, например, здесь: *"Какие красивые деревья и, в сущности, какая должна быть около них красивая жизнь!"; "И вдруг мне мелькнула мысль, ведь, в сущности, ты не могла успеть бы прислать мне ответное письмо..."* // "Говоря по факту" — это вообще деепричастный оборот, а не вводное. И к тому же он не имеет смысла. Факт — это не то, "по чему" можно говорить.

Comment: "по сути говоря" - это не деепричастный оборот, ибо у него нет субъекта. Это именно вводная конструкция см например справочник Фрамполь.  "по факту" = "говоря фактами" - так я надеюсь можно?

Comment: @user190920 "говоря фактически" есть в Нацкорпусе всего два раза, у одного автора. Это неверный оборот, потому что бессмысленный. "Говоря фактами" — тут не вижу ошибки.

Comment: Это все не аргументы, ибо форму я могу менять как угодно, доказывая вашим методом вводность и причастность. Например так "по факту" = "оперируя только фактами" итп. Что касается красивых деревьев, там не вижу разницы в смысле. "По сути" вполне подставляемо.

Comment: @user190920 ну, что я могу сказать... Только одно: если Вы чего-то не видите, это не означает, что этого нет. Намедни уже забегал один товарищ с вопросами про вводные, его тоже никакой ответ не устраивал: он тоже не мог различить то, что различали другие. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/470306/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0

Comment: Что я могу сказать... Если долго смотреть на две одинаковых картинки, то они постепенно начинают все сильнее различаться. Но вводные слова это неустоявшаяся область грамматики, так что тут я не один такой.