# Почему "по факту" не может быть вводным словом?

Tags: вводные-слова

Мой вопрос связан с темой, которая уже обсуждалась [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/470428/Мозготрах-с-вводными-словами-Почему-По-сути-вводное-а-По-факту-нет](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/470428/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85-%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%9F%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B0-%D0%9F%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82)

*По сути, это война*.
*По факту это война.*
Почему 1-е предложение это вводная конструкция, а 2-е - нет?

Я искала материал, связанный не с правописанием вводных слов, а с пониманием их грамматики и семантики. По существу обсуждаемой темы я могу сказать следующее.

Я тоже **плохо различаю вводные слова.** Более того, я полагаю, что  их плохо различают практически все (это такая вещь в себе, «непостижимая» как бы).  Вводные слова выражают **отношение говорящего к сказанному**, так что большинство наречных выражений  имеют парные вводные слова.

Почему "по факту/фактически/с точки зрения фактов» не может выражать такое отношение? А если может, то почему его нельзя считать вводным? Вот Грамота.ру всем внушает, что «нет, никогда и ни в коем случае». А почему, собственно говоря?

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ ОТ 28.06.2022**

Я посмотрела примеры из Нацкорпуса **с обособлением слова "фактически"**. К сожалению, большинство из них неудачные. Там по структуре и семантике слово занимает  позицию именно **наречия и обособления не требует.** Вероятно, такие нюансы еще не понимаются нашими пользователями, поэтому и существует общий запрет. Но есть предложения, где "фактически" **можно обособить** как вводное слово:

То есть, **фактически**, это был непрерывный процесс ― изготовление, смена, изготовление, смена… [Мы работаем на грани известного и неизвестного // «Знание - сила», 2006]

Очень интересен этот период погружения ― это, **фактически**, падение со скоростью до 40 метров в минуту. [Александр Клейн. Зов бездны: глубины, тонкости и сложности, где только ты сам // «Пятое измерение», 2003

Он, **фактически**, отказался от него, от своих дорогих ему персонажей, признав их несовременными и устаревшими. [Григорий Фукс. Двое в барабане // «Звезда», 2003]

― Тогда ты, **фактически**, создаешь свой собственный мир. [Желания: единственный мотор, который нас не обманывает // «Пятое измерение», 2003]

Comment: Когда "по сути" — вводное, то это сокращение сочетания "по сути дела". У "по факту" такой "полной формы" нет. Поэтому сравнивать "по сути" и "по факту" не совсем корректно, я полагаю. // Смею, впрочем, заметить, что в Нацкорпусе без малого полторы сотни случаев "фактически" как вводного: https://clck.ru/rekRP

Comment: Я в своем вопросе не сравниваю две эти формы, а рассматриваю только "по факту". Предлог ПО обозначает соответствие.  ФАКТИЧЕСКИЙ, -ая, -ое. 1. Отражающий действительное состояние чего-л., соответствующий фактам. Ф-ие данные.  Кстати, обратите внимание на ед. число – по факту, что придает сочетанию значение обобщенности, устойчивости. Ведь в прямом значении там было бы "по фактам" (о войне по одному факту не судят). И еще о сравнении с пресловутым "говоря" – вот зачем  мы используем эту проверку? Она  только заводит в тупик, но при этом ничего не доказывает по существу дела.

Comment: Это касается и всех других "переделок", сравнений одного с другим и подстановок. Что с того, что "по факту дела" мы не говорим? Кстати, "фактически" тоже запрещается считать вводным. Низзя! Ну и вывод. Как вы думаете, можно "по факту", "фактически" считать вводными словами и обособлять? В чем запрет-то?  У наших грамматиков даже список "лжевводных слов" имеется.

Comment: Я не исследовал вопрос вводных слов (сочетаний) достаточно досконально, чтобы разбираться и на уровне формальном, и на уровне понятийном, какое слово (сочетание) можно считать вводным, какое нет.

Comment: @Nektoid
Тогда лучше и не разбирайтесь, а то потратите жизнь впустую ;))  Но все-таки мне огорчительно, что никто мне на мой вопрос не ответит. У вас нет чего-нибудь для поднятия настроения?

Comment: Сожалею, но у меня у самого приступ тафофилии, так что для поднятия настроения могу разве что скинуть фото какого-нибудь изящного гробика)

Comment: https://orfographia.ru/po-faktu-vydelyaetsya-zapyatymi-ili-net/

Comment: Привет! Полезная статья, оформите комментарий как ответ, а я его приму.  А то на мои вопросы никто уже не отвечает, будто и нет их вовсе. Ну и я не буду отвечать. Не хотите меня заменить , уже отдохнули, наверное. Как ваши дела, как настроение?

Comment: Приветствую. Уже почти этим не занимаюсь. Оно для меня стало легко. А когда-то было жутко сложно, одна проблема порождала другую, мозги кипели. Мне здесь нечего добавить. Сразу показалось, что оно молодёжное, разговорное. Скорее всего, во времена Розенталя не было такого употребления. А Грамота живёт по Розенталю в основном. Время идёт очень быстро, ничего не успеваю. Последние ваши вопросы не простые. Они значительно сложнее, чем кажутся. Чем умнее вы становитесь, тем меньше людей могут вам помочь.

Comment: Я в кое-каком учебнике только что нашел, что это слово обособлено. Позже задам сюда вопрос по этому поводу.